# set time to live option in gcm

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am doing an android app which uses gcm.I have to set in the server side as the message should be deleted after one day if it is not delivered.Please help me.Following is the function for sending notification to gcm server.

```
public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message, $coll_key) {
        // include config
        include_once './config.php';

        // Set POST variables
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

        $fields = array(
            'collapse_key' => $coll_key,
            'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
            'data' => $message,
        );

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key='.GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `time_to_live` parameter and give it a value which equals the max number of seconds you wish your message to be stored in GCM servers without being delivered.

```
$fields = array(
    'collapse_key' => $coll_key,
    'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
    'data' => $message,
    'time_to_live' => $time_to_live,
);
```